# Scan for devices using the CastCompanionLibrary for Android

Tags: android, google-cast

I have a `ChromeCast` app out and I am using the `CastCompanionLibrary` provided by **Google**. The most common complaint I receive about my app is that sometimes the `ChromeCast` icon does not appear, even when other `ChromeCast` enabled applications show it.

I have experienced this myself as well, so I know it isn't just user error. I open up my app and see that the icon is not visible, then I open something else like **Netlfix** or **Youtube**, and the icon appears immediately.

Usually, just resetting the phone will do the trick. However, I hate having to tell my users to do that. Is there a way, while still using the `CastCompanionLibrary`, to force a scan for `ChromeCast` devices on the network?

Comment: If you were using `MediaRouteActionProvider` directly, there's a flag for that.

Comment: I believe Netflix and YouTube are still using the original non public sdk which uses a different api for discovery. I seem to recall reading on the Google cast developers g+ community that Google was aware of the discovery issues with the new api. Have you checked the issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

Netflix and Youtube use the private SDK which uses a different method of discovery.

We've found that if you use a wireless network with less traffic that you will be more successful. Also the new cast SDK uses mdns so you must turn off settings that would prevent that from working. See this link for tips getting it to work with your router: https://support.google.com/chromecast/table/3477832?hl=en&ref_topic=3447927

Issue is discussed here:
https://plus.google.com/105752620866737875195/posts/VZcBCj4retD
https://plus.google.com/113623946819457317474/posts/DnycY9PbNxC

Comment: Also if you have your users use "Photowall" made by Google then they'll see the same issue. Ask them to test using that app to confirm if it's a problem with your app or the discoverability of the chromecast